# Publish from VS works, xcopy of dotnet publish does not

Tags: iis, tfs, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a dotnet core app, full framework referencing a ef6 lib. Running publish to IIS from VS2017 works fine.

When running the following from TFS2017 it does not work (ef6 strange errors)

- nuget restore ***.sln
- dotnet restore src/CoolApp/CoolApp.csproj
- dotnet publish src/CoolApp/CoolApp.csproj --configuration release --output $(drop)
- (when releasing) Copy everything from $(drop) to IIS website

Comparing content the exe is of course different, and exe.config also.

Any ideas what we've missed?

Comment: what errors when you get, could you post the errors here? And could you give more details about what are differences?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TFS 2017 Update1. If you are using TFS 2017 Update1, please don't use the .netCore(preview) step first. Try to use the tasks in this document about [build your ASP.NET Core app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core) to see if it works. Steps are:

1. Command Line(Dotnet restore).
2. Visual Studio Build. Cause your project is created in VS2017, select VS 2017 in this step to build.
3. Command Line(Dot restore). publish --configuration release --output $(drop)
4. Publish build artifacts. 
   When in release, copy the artifacts from $(drop).